# If $a^{-1}$ has a cube root, so does $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a^{-1}$ has a cube root [in a group], then so does $a$.

#### Attempt

Suppose $a^{-1} = bbb.$ Then, $b^{-1}(a^{-1})b^{-1} = b^{-1}(bbb)b^{-1} \to b = b^{-1}(a^{-1})b^{-1}.$ Now I am not sure if it holds up. I have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Can you edit this to call $b$ the cube root of $a^{-1}$? I can't follow the argument as it stands.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that you are talking about modular arithmetic here? IS that right?

Comment: I edited the OP. As for the modular arithmetic, I am not sure :)

Comment: Can you define what $a^{-1}$ means, then, please, and give one or two examples? Does every element $k$ have an inverse $k^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should specify that $a$ is an element of an arbitrary group (I assume that's what you're interested in).

Your proof only works for elements $a$ such that $a^{-1}=aaa$, since you assume that right from the start for no reason. In other words, you're assuming that not only does $a^{-1}$ have a cube root, but that that cube root is also its inverse. What you have after that is a correct proof that such elements do indeed have a cube root (namely $a^{-1}$).

What you perhaps meant to write was "Suppose there exists $b$ such that $a^{-1}=bbb$", in other words, assume $a^{-1}$ has a cube root, and then figure out what it is. With this correction, the rest of your proof falls apart immediately: multiplying by $a^{-1}$ we just get $a^{-1}a^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}bbba^{-1}$, which tells us nothing about $a$ having an inverse.

Thus, your proof should start with "Let $a^{-1}=bbb$". Note that it's *let* and not *suppose*. You're not supposing anything, you're just giving a name to the cube root, which was already supposed to exist in the problem statement.

Comment: Let $a^{-1} = bbb$  for some $b.$ Then $aa^{-1} = e = abbb \to b^{-1} = baa^{-1}b^{-1} = e.$ So, $a = eee = b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}.$ Would that work?

Comment: @Marko As soon as you got to $a=eee$ you should have spotted a big, big problem - $eee$ is $e$, so you've just said that any element whose inverse has a cube root is the identity! I actually can't pinpoint where you went wrong because at the point where you have the $\to$ sign you seem to have done about five things at once. I agree that $baa^{-1}b^{-1}=e$, but why do you claim that the left hand side equals $b^{-1}$? Furthermore, what does that have to do with $a$ being equal to either $eee$ or $b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** If $a^{-1} = bbb$ then 
$$(a^{-1})^{-1}=???$$

Comment: $a = b^{-3} ?  $

Comment: @Marko You should be careful with notation until you have more experience. What do you mean by $b^{-3}$? In a group, $x^{-1}$ is defined by the group axioms, but what does $x^{-3}$ mean in an arbitrary group?

Comment: @ Jack M, $b^{-3} = (b^{-1})^3 = b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}. x^{-3}$ means that $x^{-1}$ is the cube root of some $y$.

Comment: @Marko Exactly, although you might check that you can prove $(bbb)^{-1}=b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(bbb)^{-1}=b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}$

So, from $a^{-1}=bbb$ you have:
$$a=\left(a^{-1}\right)^{-1}=(bbb)^{-1}=b^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}
$$